# How do I stream Live Video

Tags: video, streaming, live-video

I'm looking for solutions that will allow me to have a Live Video feed setup at one location and, via the internet, watch the video stream at a remote location.

The goal is to have a live high quality video training session that remote users can watch from their own locations.

Any technology will work. High Quality is a must. I'm most familiar with C# and Microsoft solutions.

Here is how I understand it might work:

**For Provider**

1. Get Camera (I currently have a high definition video camera)
2. Plug Camera into computer (How, video capture card?)
3. Use Software to Capture video (What software?)
4. Use Software to stream to client (What software?)

**For Client**

5. Use Software to point to Video Source (What Software?)
6. Plug Computer into Projector

Answer (score 1):

I think the soultion for you is DaCast, a self-service platform for live streaming. When you sign up an account, you are 20 minutes away from your first streaming. As long as you have a webcam, you can easily stream live throughout the internet. You can somply send a link of your DaCast channel page to all viewers, they can watch the stream at any location. Also, you can embed the code to your own web site or blog, then your viewers can watch it, too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Video Lan Client (VLC)  They have ability to stream/capture video from either a video camera or video file.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

(there is a checkbox at the bottom of the new dialog for streaming/saving options)

http://ashishware.com/Video.shtml