# Streaming live video to a web site

Tags: php, mysql, macos, streaming, live

I've received a request asking if it's possible to stream live video to a web site. The person requesting this has a notebook running MacOS, a professional camera that can be connected up using Firewire and a web site with PHP/MySQL.

What solutions exist to stream the video out on the Internet and, if practical, what would be necessary to display the live video on a web page in programming terms ?

Edit:
There are these topics on stackoverflow but I'm not sure if they're relevant:
[Live Video Streaming with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223983/live-video-streaming-with-php)
[How do I stream Live Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341223/how-do-i-stream-live-video)

There is also this page over at apple.com:
http://www.apple.com/quicktime/tutorials/delivery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top of my head, [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). It has the ability to stream Live Video from a given capture device. There is a how to guide [here](http://www.iupui.edu/~nmstream/live/howtovlc.html).

One shortcoming I noticed is the end user must have VLC installed as well. But I am sure there is a way around it with enough research.

Comment: Apparently VLC can act as a streaming server (see diagram on the apple page). That leaves the question of whether it's possible to relay the stream to a web site and diffuse it as you would with a stream from a webcam.

Answer (score -1):

After some searching, it appears that the solution might be as simple as entering some html markup to point a player to the streaming server. I'm still unsure of this, however, and some tests will need to be carried out.

Comment: "as simple"... except that you actually need a streaming server to do this. - There are free ready-made solutions http://ustream.tv is one of them.